# rule failed test while trying to upgrade pmd from 6.17.0 to 6.18.0

Tags: pmd

the rule is

"//Reference[matches(@literal, \"^\$[^!]+\") and ./preceding-sibling::Text and ./following-sibling::Text]"

for your convenient I will provide the project and you can mvn-test it.

the whole project is at https://github.com/XenoAmess/p3c/tree/1605f4d1b9c6a505074be5328953af26f578e190/p3c-pmd

the Rule class is com.alibaba.p3c.pmd.lang.vm.rule.other.UseQuietReferenceNotationRule

I tried to look through your update log, and found nothing related.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a side-effect of fixing https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1923. It has been fixed by using real/full name in the rule context (see https://github.com/pmd/pmd/pull/1982). In unit tests, the file name used is "n/a", which is now interpreted as the file "a" in directory "n". `RuleContext::getSourceCodeFilename` returns just the filename and not the full path. To retrieve the full path `RuleContext::getSourceCodeFile` can be used.

Your rule UseQuietReferenceNotationRule checks the filename ([UseQuietReferenceNotationRule.java:65](https://github.com/XenoAmess/p3c/blob/27f2314ba4168508143eb90fab124e547b426099/p3c-pmd/src/main/java/com/alibaba/p3c/pmd/lang/vm/rule/other/UseQuietReferenceNotationRule.java#L65)) which is now not "n/a" anymore in the unit tests but "a". You can "fix" the unit test by simply changing UT_FILE_NAME to "a" (see [UseQuietReferenceNotationRule.java:45](https://github.com/XenoAmess/p3c/blob/27f2314ba4168508143eb90fab124e547b426099/p3c-pmd/src/main/java/com/alibaba/p3c/pmd/lang/vm/rule/other/UseQuietReferenceNotationRule.java#L45)).

Alternatively you can change the rule to use `ctx.getSourceCodeFile().toString()` to recover the full pathname in [UseQuietReferenceNotationRule.java:62](https://github.com/XenoAmess/p3c/blob/27f2314ba4168508143eb90fab124e547b426099/p3c-pmd/src/main/java/com/alibaba/p3c/pmd/lang/vm/rule/other/UseQuietReferenceNotationRule.java#L62). Although the file doesn't exist, it still points to "n/a".

An alternative for checking the path names in the rule itself might be [File exclusion/inclusion patterns](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html#filtering-the-processed-files).

Also, contributions on https://github.com/pmd/pmd are welcome if you think the rules make sense for a wider audience.